# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' (HTML send input to Python)

Tags: python, html

```
#!C:\Users\aan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
import numpy as np
import skfuzzy as fuzz
import cgi
from skfuzzy import control as ctrl
print("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

def fuz():
    temperature = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(0,100,1), 'temperature')
    humidity = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(0,100,1), 'humidity')
    heatfan = ctrl.Consequent(np.arange(0,100,1), 'heatfan')
    coldfan = ctrl.Consequent(np.arange(0,100,1), 'coldfan')
    humidifier = ctrl.Consequent(np.arange(0,100,1), 'humidifier')

    ############################################################################ MEMBERSHIP
    temperature['very_cold'] = fuzz.trapmf(temperature.universe, [0,0,14,15])
    temperature['cold'] = fuzz.trapmf(temperature.universe, [11,15,21,22])
    temperature['normal'] = fuzz.trapmf(temperature.universe, [21,22,28,30])
    temperature['hot'] = fuzz.trapmf(temperature.universe, [29,29,35,36])
    temperature['very_hot'] = fuzz.trapmf(temperature.universe, [35,36,100,100])

    
    humidity['very_dry'] = fuzz.trapmf(humidity.universe, [0,0,39,40])
    humidity['dry'] = fuzz.trapmf(humidity.universe, [39,40,59,60])
    humidity['moist'] = fuzz.trapmf(humidity.universe, [59,60,80,81])
    humidity['wet'] = fuzz.trapmf(humidity.universe, [79,81,100,100])


    heatfan['off'] = fuzz.trapmf(heatfan.universe, [0,0,9,10])
    heatfan['slow'] = fuzz.trapmf(heatfan.universe, [5,10,50,60])
    heatfan['fast'] = fuzz.trapmf(heatfan.universe, [50,60,100,100])


    coldfan['off'] = fuzz.trapmf(coldfan.universe, [0,0,9,10])
    coldfan['slow'] = fuzz.trapmf(coldfan.universe, [9,10,59,60])
    coldfan['fast'] = fuzz.trapmf(coldfan.universe, [59,60,100,100])


    humidifier['off'] = fuzz.trapmf(humidifier.universe, [0,0,9,10])
    humidifier['low'] = fuzz.trapmf(humidifier.universe, [9,10,59,60])
    humidifier['high'] = fuzz.trapmf(humidifier.universe, [59,60,100,100])


    rule1=ctrl.Rule((temperature['very_cold']&humidity['very_dry']),(coldfan['off'],heatfan['fast'],humidifier['high']))
    rule2=ctrl.Rule((temperature['cold']&humidity['very_dry']),(coldfan['off'],heatfan['slow'],humidifier['high']))
    rule3=ctrl.Rule((temperature['normal']&humidity['very_dry']),(coldfan['off'],heatfan['off'],humidifier['high']))
    rule4=ctrl.Rule((temperature['hot']&humidity['very_dry']),(coldfan['slow'],heatfan['off'],humidifier['high']))
    rule5=ctrl.Rule((temperature['very_hot']&humidity['very_dry']),(coldfan['fast'],heatfan['off'],humidifier['high']))
    rule6=ctrl.Rule((temperature['very_cold']&humidity['dry']),(coldfan['off'],heatfan['fast'],humidifier['low']))
    rule7=ctrl.Rule((temperature['cold']&humidity['dry']),(coldfan['off'],heatfan['slow'],humidifier['low']))
    rule8=ctrl.Rule((temperature['normal']&humidity['dry']),(coldfan['off'],heatfan['off'],humidifier['low']))
    rule9=ctrl.Rule((temperature['hot']&humidity['dry']),(coldfan['slow'],heatfan['off'],humidifier['low']))
    rule10=ctrl.Rule((temperature['very_hot']&humidity['dry']),(coldfan['fast'],heatfan['off'],humidifier['low']))
    rule11=ctrl.Rule(((temperature['very_cold']&humidity['moist'])|(temperature['very_cold']&humidity['wet'])),(coldfan['off'],heatfan['fast'],humidifier['off']))
    rule12=ctrl.Rule(((temperature['cold']&humidity['moist'])|(temperature['cold']&humidity['wet'])),(coldfan['off'],heatfan['slow'],humidifier['off']))
    rule13=ctrl.Rule(((temperature['normal']&humidity['moist'])|(temperature['normal']&humidity['wet'])),(coldfan['off'],heatfan['off'],humidifier['off']))
    rule14=ctrl.Rule(((temperature['hot']&humidity['moist'])|(temperature['hot']&humidity['wet'])),(coldfan['slow'],heatfan['off'],humidifier['off']))
    rule15=ctrl.Rule(((temperature['very_hot']&humidity['moist'])|(temperature['very_hot']&humidity['wet'])),(coldfan['fast'],heatfan['off'],humidifier['off']))
    output_f_ctrl = ctrl.ControlSystem([rule1, rule2, rule3, rule4, rule5, rule6, rule7, rule8, rule9, rule10, rule11, rule12, rule13, rule14, rule15])
    output_f = ctrl.ControlSystemSimulation(output_f_ctrl)
    temp = int(form.getvalue('temp'))
    hum = int(form.getvalue('hum'))
    output_f.input['temperature'] = temp
    output_f.input['humidity'] = hum
    print("Current Temperature =",temp)
    print("Current Humidity =",hum)
    output_f.compute()
    cfspeed=output_f.output['coldfan']
    hfspeed=output_f.output['heatfan']
    humidifier_s=output_f.output['humidifier']
    print("Heat_Fan =",hfspeed)
    print("Cold_Fan =",cfspeed)
    print("Humidifier =",humidifier_s)


fuz()
```

When I'm trying to get the HTML form inputs and send to python as inputs, I'm getting this error **TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'** anyone know why? maybe is because the temp and hum inputs there? When I removed the int() the code cant run either....

Comment: One of the `form.getvalue()` calls is returning `None`. Make sure you used the correct input field names.

Comment: what is the meaning of returning None? is that suppose to return to somewhere else?

Comment: It's the default value if there's no form field with that name.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the value is NoneType (ie nothing returned by the function). For example:

```
temp = int(form.getvalue('temp'))
```

form.getvalue('temp') is returning NoneType

Is it possible the 'temp' field isn't present?

Comment: Yeah i think is because the temp and hum too, any solution for that?

Comment: What is the URL of the get request? The solution is to either add the two values to the URL, remove them from the code, or check if the keys exist using if statements before trying to work with their return values.